# BufferedReader returns null from a file with text

Tags: java, null, bufferedreader

My program encodes a String using the Polybuis cypher, where each char in a given  String is represented by two encoded chars.
The encoded message is built by creating a char array and appending, to a StringBuilder, two chars for every char in the message, followed by a space.

```
for (int add = 2; add < finalEncodedMessage.length; add+=2) {
            encodedMessageWithSpaces.append(' ');
            encodedMessageWithSpaces.append(finalEncodedMessage[add]);
            encodedMessageWithSpaces.append(finalEncodedMessage[add+1]);
        }
```

The final message is represented by a String, and saved to file using BufferedWriter:

```
outputFile = selectedFile;
        try {
            bufferedOutput = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));
            bufferedOutput.write(encrytedText);
            bufferedOutput.flush();

            bufferedOutput.close();
```

The problem is when I try to read this file I am getting null, regardless of the content:

File content Example with encrypted text:

FA DD FF VF XF FF AD AG GV GG VF AF XG FA FD DG DF DD FD FF DF GX FF
XG FA VG GG FA DF VX FA FG FF FD DF GF DD VG GD DD XG

Reading the file reruns null:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (fileName.exists()) {
            try {

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName)));


                while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(br.readLine());
                    sb.append(br.readLine() + "\n");
                }

                br.close();
```

I can't figure out  why the BufferedReader is reaching end of file without reading a line of text.

Input  appreciated.

Comment: You are throwing away the result of the readline call and then doing more calls. Since your file has only one line that means you won't see anything. Assign the result to a variable before competing with null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each br.readLine() call will read the next line. Your while loop will read 3 lines each iteration because of that.
Usually you want to store the read line into a variable for processing and only call readLine() once per iteration.

```
String line = br.readLine() 
while (line != null) {
    // do stuff with line
    line = br.readLine()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call `readLine()`, the buffered reader attempts to read a line.

Your code *as you have written it* calls `readLine()` three times for each iteration of the loop ... and only captures one out of three of the lines of text.  (Every third line to be precise.)

It looks like you have seen the following idiom and tried to use it without fully understanding it:

```
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
```

Note that you must capture the result of the `readLine()` call and store it in a variable.